# Where is the out by one error in peak finding code?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am implementing the recursive algorithm for finding a peak in a 1d array [finding a peak in a 1d array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-peak-in-a-given-array/).  My solution seems to be out by one and I am not sure why. First, here is a naive algorithm to check the answers:

```
def naive(A):
    n = len(A)
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if A[0] >= A[1]:
        return 0
    if A[n-1]  >= A[n-2]:
        return n-1
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        if A[i] >= A[i-1] and A[i] >= A[i+1]:
            return i
    return -1
```

Here is my (broken) recursive solution:

```
def recursive(A, start, end):
    n = end - start
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return 0 if A[start] >= A[start+1] else 1
    if A[n//2] >= A[n//2+1] and A[n//2] >= A[n//2 - 1]:
        return n//2
    elif A[n//2 - 1] >= A[n//2]:
        return recursive(A, 0, n//2)
    else:
        return n//2 + 1 + recursive(A, n//2+1, n)
```

Here is the result of testing:

```
n = 10
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
naive(A)
Out[1]: 9
recursive(A, 0, len(A))
Out[2]: 10
```

The recursive answer is wrong.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Which one is wrong?

Comment: @wwii The recursive one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your recursive function you use `n = end - start` and then use `n // 2` to get the middle point. This does not seem to be correct.

Example data to illustrate the error:

```
start | end |  n |  n // 2
---------------------------
    0 |  11 | 11 |       5
    5 |  11 |  6 |       3
```

You would need to add a value to `n // 2` to get the middle point.

Also, you should use `start` and `end` instead of `0` and `n` to call the function recursively.

This seems to work:

```
def peak_recursive2(A, start, end):
    n = end - start + 1
    middle = start + n // 2
    # print(start, end, middle, A[start:end+1])

    if n == 1:
        return start
    if n == 2:
        return start if A[start] >= A[start + 1] else end

    if A[middle] >= A[middle + 1] and A[middle] >= A[middle - 1]:
        return middle
    elif A[middle - 1] >= A[middle]:
        return peak_recursive2(A, start, middle)
    else:
        return peak_recursive2(A, middle + 1, end)
```